# automorphism group and group presentation

Tags: gr.group-theory

When does a group presentation of a group $G = < x_{1} , \ldots , x_{n} | r_{i}(x_{1} , \ldots , x_{n} ), \;  1 \leq i \leq k> $ produce all the elements of $Aut(G)$ by permuting the $x_{i}$?

Comment: Very rarely, I think it has to be either finite or be virtually Z. 

Comment: Indeed, such group G would have to have finite automorphism group.  Looking at the inner automorphisms, one immediately sees that G is either finite or is an extension of the infinite cyclic group with finite kernel: $1\to F \to G \to Z\to 1$, where F is finite. 

Comment: I deleted my comment that the fundamental group of the Klein bottle is an example, I forgot that the Dehn twist makes the automorphism group infinite.